# Datawedge doesnt return Userbank data from RFID tag

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, datawedge, zebra-scanners

i am using a zebra MC3300X device to read RFID tags.
I use intent output to send the data to my broadcast receiver. But i can only read the tag id when i doesnt select any memorybank. In this case the broadcast receiver works correct. When i choose user memory bank or EPC or TID the datawedge app doesn't send any intent to my broadcast receiver

My Broadcast receiver:

```
public class ScanReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string data = intent.GetStringExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.data_string");
        Toast.MakeText(context, data, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

Someone any ideas?